# How do you output several lines of the $_POST variable

Tags: php

How do I output several lines of the `$_POST` variable ?
When I keep outputting the result I only get the last `$_POST` variable
Thanks for helping

Comment: Please show the code you are using.

Comment: Some sort of loop would probably help but ditto on Pekka's comment

Answer (score 2):

If you want more detailed information about what's being stored in `$_POST` you can use

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

This will return the key, contents and type of each entry

```
print_r($_POST);
```

This will display the key and contents of each entry.

If you want to cycle through the contents of `$_POST` and format the output you can use.

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    print $key.' is '.$value.'<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "the last $_POST variable"? Please provide the code snipped and the desired output format.

echo $_POST; -> "Array"
print_r ($_POST); -> detailed output of the array's contents.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    echo $key . ': ' . $value . '<br />';
}
```